# Is it safe to return "console.error" instead of "undefined"?

Tags: javascript, output, return-value

I have a piece of code that looks like this:

```
// very important checks:
if (blah_blah_blah === true) {
  console.error("Whoops! Something went wrong!");
  return undefined;
}

/*
 * carry on doing things...
 */

// more important checks:
if (blah_blah_blah_blah === true) {
  console.error("Whoops! Something else went wrong!");
  return undefined;
}

/*
 * carry on doing more things...
 */
```

The `return undefined;` part seemed redundant as I could just do `return console.error("...");`, which I have tried and *seems* to work the same.

I've tried checking what [`console.error()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/error) officially returns on MDN but haven't been able to find any info on that.

I've also tried checking the return via Node.js in my console and the output is:

```
> console.error("Hello World!")
Hello World!
undefined
>
```

My question is; is it safe to return the return value of `console.error` instead of `undefined`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### It's OK, but not a good practice.

`console.error` is an implementation-dependent function (it isn't even part of the ECMAScript standard), so its return value is also unknown. However, (as far as I know) it returns `undefined` both in the major browsers and Node.js.

So these three can be said to be equal:

```
return console.error('Oops')
```

```
console.error('Oops')
return undefined
```

```
console.error('Oops')
return
```

### Although it works, it isn't good

Logging an error shouldn't replace the exception throwing mechanism.

The following is much better:

```
throw new Error('Oops')
```

Why?

- Throwing an exception halts the execution of callers as well, unless handled properly.
- Logging can not be prevented by caller code *even if* it knows how to handle the error. That can be confusing.
- Error and stack trace still printed to the console if the error isn't handled.

I've explained that in detail [in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60383852/8376184).

Answer (score 1):

Batter than returning `console.error` you should return `new Error("Error message")`.

And log error once at after calling function which returns this error.

```
function someFunction() {
   // very important checks:
   if (blah_blah_blah === true) {
     return new Error("Whoops! Something went wrong!");
   }

   /*
    * carry on doing things...
    */

   // more important checks:
   if (blah_blah_blah_blah === true) {
     return new Error("Whoops! Something else went wrong!");
   }

   /*
    * carry on doing more things...
     */
 }
 let returnValue = someFunction()
 if(returnValue instanceof Error) {
    console.error(returnValue)
 }
```